# Update the aws-auth yml return Mapping values error

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, yaml

I am trying to update the aws-auth config file but I can't update the yml file and It always return `yaml: mapping values are not allowed in this context`

[image]

I test this yml context everywhere and all return ok but why I cant patch this to aws-auth.

Comment: try to replace `build` with the same value as the `rolearn`

Comment: @AmitBaranes, I tried to download the current one and re-patch it but still having the same issue. Even the same file having the issue.